# How to find all elements by value in list in JSonPath

Tags: json, xpath, jsonpath

I can find a person who has a hobby of "Dance" by doing the following:

```
Xpath = Persons/Person/Hobbies/Hobby[text()="Dance"]/../..
```

```
<Persons>
    <Person>
        <Name>David</Name>
        <Age>20</Age>
        <Hobbies>
            <Hobby>Sing</Hobby>
            <Hobby>Dance</Hobby>
        </Hobbies>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Frank</Name>
        <Age>30</Age>
        <Hobbies>
            <Hobby>Sing</Hobby>
            <Hobby>Read</Hobby>
        </Hobbies>
    </Person>
</Persons>
```

[image]

How would I do the same for JSONPath? For example, I have this json:

```
[
    {"name": "david", "age": 20, "hobbies": ["dance", "sing"]},
    {"name": "frank", "age": 30, "hobbies": ["sing", "read"]}
]
```

So far I have `$[*].hobbies[*]` but I'm not sure how to go further. I am using https://jsonpath.com/ to test. The result I want should be:

```
{"name": "david", "age": 20, "hobbies": ["dance", "sing"]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do a nested filter expression query.

```
$[?(@.hobbies[?(@ == 'dance')])]
```

The first `[]` syntax gets you inside the outer array.

At this point, you need a filter query, which looks at each item.  For each item, you want to look at each item of the `hobbies` array, so you need

- `.hobbies` to get that array
- another  `[]` to get you inside that array
- another filter query to check for `dance`

Comment: Thanks for this -- is there varying support for JSONPath? On jsonpath.com it says `jsonPath: Unexpected token '?': _$_v.hobbies[?_$_v == 'dance']`

Comment: Yes. The answer I gave should work in most implementations, but nested queries like that isn't supported everywhere.  The implementation may also require `()` for the expression.  I've updated the above to include them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but since you obviously know XPath already, and you raise some question about variation in support for JSONPath, I thought I'd point out that you can also query JSON data in standard XPath 3.1 (the latest version of XPath). e.g.

Applying the following XPath to your JSON array:

```
?*[?hobbies="dance"]
```

Result:

```json
{"hobbies":["dance","sing"],"name":"david","age":20}
```

[XPath fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=%3F*%5B%3Fhobbies%3D%22dance%22%5D&input=%5B%0A++++%7B%22name%22%3A+%22david%22%2C+%22age%22%3A+20%2C+%22hobbies%22%3A+%5B%22dance%22%2C+%22sing%22%5D%7D%2C%0A++++%7B%22name%22%3A+%22frank%22%2C+%22age%22%3A+30%2C+%22hobbies%22%3A+%5B%22sing%22%2C+%22read%22%5D%7D%0A%5D%0A&input-type=JSON)